# Checkbox Array, Jquery, PHP

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox, mysqli

I have a `main.php` page with some checkboxes and a textbox, what I am trying to achieve is on selecting of "`Select All` or any of the checkboxes the values should be passed".The checkbox change function should trigger and post the data to `ajaxData.php`. The Ajaxdata.php should return the respective team members name back to the `main.php` page and display the `fname` values in a textbox.

The problem right now is nothing happens on click on any of the checkboxes

My `main.php` page is below

```
Select All <input type="checkbox" name="select_all" id="select_all" value="1">

Pythons<input type="checkbox" name="select[]" id="team" value="Pythons">
Wipers <input type="checkbox" name="select[]" id="team" value="Wipers">
<input type="textbox" name="first_name" value="">
<script>

$("#select_all").change(function() {
   var select_all = $(this).val();
 alert('1');
    if(select_all){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajaxData.php',
            data:'select_all='+select_all,
            success:function(html){
                $('#first_name').html(html);

            }
        }); 
    }else{
        //$('#carrier').html('<option value="">Select State First</option>');

    }

</script>
```

`ajaxData.php` code looks like the following

```
if(isset($_POST["select_all"]) && !empty($_POST["select_all"])){

$select_sql="SELECT * FROM member WHERE team_id = ".$_POST['select_all']." ORDER BY name ASC";
 $result=mysqli_query($con,$select_sql);
 $cnt=mysqli_num_rows($result);
 if($cnt > 0)
 {
        while($results=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {

            if($results['id'] !=0 )
                {
                 echo $results['fname']                               
            }
}
```

Comment: Check passed/returned values in developers console.

Comment: @u_mulder Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: your code has very bad format.. weird braces.. missing braces.. Is that exactly how you have it? fix it so we can continue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `});` at the end, that's why you will get an error like `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`:

```
$("#select_all").change(function() {
   var select_all = $(this).val();
 alert('1');
    if(select_all){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajaxData.php',
            data:'select_all='+select_all,
            success:function(html){
                $('#first_name').html(html);

            }
        }); 
    }else{
        //$('#carrier').html('<option value="">Select State First</option>');

    }
}); //this is missing in your code
```

And in your PHP script you are missing some `}`(two more exactly), and also missing `;` after `echo $results['fname']`, so change `echo $results['fname']` to `echo $results['fname'];` try this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["select_all"]) && !empty($_POST["select_all"])){

$select_sql="SELECT * FROM member WHERE team_id = ".$_POST['select_all']." ORDER BY name ASC";
 $result=mysqli_query($con,$select_sql);
 $cnt=mysqli_num_rows($result);
 if($cnt > 0){
        while($results=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

            if($results['id'] !=0 ){
                 echo $results['fname'];                               
            }
       }
 }

}
```